# Streaming to file in Node introduces unexpected characters

Tags: node.js

I need to write a readable stream that reads characters (some of which have a value of >128) and pipes to a write stream.  In the simple program I have knocked up from an example in the Node streams documentation, I have a problem with the introduction of characters (decimal value 194).  Given the example code

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');
var Readable = stream.Readable;
var Writable = stream.Writable;
util.inherits(ArrayStream, Readable);
util.inherits(OutStream, Writable);

function ArrayStream(opt, length, array) {
  Readable.call(this, opt);
  this._max = length;
  this._index = 1;
  this._array = array;
}
ArrayStream.prototype._read = function() {
  var i = this._index++;
  if (i > this._max)
    this.push(null);
  else {
    this.push(String.fromCharCode(this._array[i-1]));
  }
};

function OutStream(opt) {
  Writable.call(this, opt);
}

OutStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, next) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chunk.length ; i++) {
    console.log('     > ', chunk[i]);
  }
  next();
};

var inputArray = [5,65,66,127,128,129,170,171];
var writable = new OutStream({});
console.log('"' + String.fromCharCode(186) + '"', String.fromCharCode(170).length);
new ArrayStream({},inputArray.length, inputArray).pipe(writable);
```

I get the output

```
"º" 1
     >  5
     >  65
     >  66
     >  127
     >  194
     >  128
     >  194
     >  129
     >  194
     >  170
     >  194
     >  171
```

I would love to know why the 194s appear, and what I can do to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not in `objectMode`, node will convert the string to buffer using default `utf-8` encoding. Since utf-8 is multibyte encoding, it will represent non-ASCII characters with more than one byte. So for some characters you are getting `chunk` with more that one byte. Here is a simple example:

```
Buffer(String.fromCharCode(170)).length // 2
Buffer(String.fromCharCode(170)).toJSON() // [ 194, 170 ]

Buffer(String.fromCharCode(65)).length // 1 for ASCII
Buffer(String.fromCharCode(65)).toJSON() //  [ 65 ]
```

You don't really need to run a loop for the chunk in writable stream. The chunk as a whole represents one character:

```
OutStream.prototype._write = function(chunk, encoding, next) {      
    console.log('     > ', chunk.toString().charCodeAt(0))
    next();
};
```